# Add property to user control in vb6

Tags: properties, vb6, user-controls, activex

I am finding code like this all over the web but it does not seem to work for me,

```
    Private FText As String

Public Property Get Text() As String
  Text = FText
  lblText.Caption = Text
End Property

Public Property Let Text(ByVal Value As String)
  FText = Value
End Property
```

Let me explain more what I am doing, I am creating a command button and the only part I am stuck by is getting the caption for the control. I got the property to show 'Text' and when I type in it set the caption but then when I run the program the caption is erased! What is wrong with the code I am doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it!

```
Const m_def_Caption = "Cmd"

'Dim m_Picture As Picture
Dim m_Caption As String

Private Sub UserControl_InitProperties()
  m_Caption = m_def_Caption
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_ReadProperties(PropBag As PropertyBag)
  m_Caption = PropBag.ReadProperty("Caption", m_def_Caption)
  lblText.Caption = m_Caption
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_WriteProperties(PropBag As PropertyBag)
  Call PropBag.WriteProperty("Caption", m_Caption, m_def_Caption)
End Sub

Public Property Get Caption() As String
  Caption = m_Caption
End Property

Public Property Let Caption(ByVal New_Caption As String)
  m_Caption = New_Caption
  PropertyChanged "Caption"
End Property
```

This works, thanks for your help, and I am glad I was able to solve this myself.